# Cannot initialise angular2-localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am receiving errors when I add `LocalStorageService` to my bootstrap code. One of the errors I receive looks like this:

```
Module parse failed: /node_modules/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.ts Unexpected token (6:14)
```

I am adding this in my bootstrap.ts:

```
import {LocalStorageService, LocalStorageSubscriber} from 'angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter';

var appPromise = bootstrap(AppComponent, [ LocalStorageService,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_BINDINGS, servicesInjectables,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]); 

LocalStorageSubscriber(appPromise);
```

There are similar errors for `LocalStorageEmitter.ts`. I thought it might be an issue with TypeScript not compiling these .ts files, but there is a `tsconfig.json` in the module folder - do I need to do anything special to get these to compile? I am using webpack. I notice there are no corresponding .js files.

Comment: He is talking about TypeScript in his question...

Comment: Yes I am using TypeScript. I notice there are no .js files in the component's folder: do I need to compile it? If so, I might run into trouble when I deploy.

Comment: @serlingpa you need to compile them for sure.. but you wont run into trouble when deploy because you can include the js files in the project if you have to, or maybe use some build system like webpack or gulp which will input the js files into dist folder, or bundle everything together. If you are using angular cli it compiles for you too i think

Comment: Hmm @DenkoMancheski. We are using webpack which will do an npm install, but the process won't compile .ts scripts in node_modules folders I wouldn't've thought.